# How to clone HDD to SSD with FileVault enabled?

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, filevault, hdd

I use an Apple MacBook Pro 13'' mid-2012 with a **1 TB HDD**. FileVault is enabled so the **disk is encrypted**. I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

I purchased an **1 TB SSD** (Crucial MX 500, CT1000MX500SSD1). I want to **clone from the HDD to the SSD**, in order to transfer the data and the OS in their current state.

I want to avoid using a third-party software, so I tried to use **Disk Utility** with the "restore" feature.

How should I proceed? How should I format the SSD before?

I tried formatting the SSD under APFS. Then I launched a restore operation from my HDD (internal) to SSD (external). But it consistently fails with *"OSStatus error 28"*, saying *"could not restore - no free space on the device"*, *"the operation could not be completed"*, *"the operation failed"*, *"the destination does not have enough space"*.

[image: Disk Utility - Could not restore]

I don't understand because both disks are supposed to have the same capacity.

[image: Disk Utility - HDD details]

[image: Disk Utility - SSD details]

Answer (score 0):

The best Application to clone your HDD to a SSD is [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com).
This Application is free for one month in test mode and completely operational.

Else the **asr** command work fine for Big Sur System. I don't know if it's ok for Mojave. In this link you have an exemple : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251693650?answerId=253255271022#253255271022

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it may be a solution to the problem. But for the moment, I would like to avoid third-party software for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: Ok. I've add informations to my answer ;-}

Comment: Interesting! I'll take a look, try and keep you informed

Comment: Carbon Copy Cloner is basically a clever front-end for such as the unix dd command - it just saves the user having to get their hands dirty with complex command line stuff. I've never heard even a whisper of there being any security concerns with it.